# ScatterPlot doesn't let me tap plot points or move graph

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, graph, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to use a scatter plot from Core Plot in my iOS application. I set up Core Plot as the Core Plot wiki says, and then I copy PlotItem.h/m, PlotGallery.h/m and SimpleScatterPlot.h/m from the included Plot Gallery project into my project. The code

```
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
SimpleScatterPlot *scatterPlot = [[SimpleScatterPlot alloc]init];
[scatterPlot generateData];
[scatterPlot renderInLayer:hostView withTheme:theme];
```

runs, and the graph view is shown in my app. But I cannot move the graph view around or tap the plot points as in the Plot Gallery project. How do I set this up right?

Comment: hostView is a CPTGraphHostingView that is declared in my viewController.h and has a IBOutlet to a CPTGraphHostingView in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plot Gallery is a poor starting point for a simple Core Plot demonstration. It has a lot of extra "stuff" to support generating a table view with thumbnails of all the different plots. <strike>The `-renderInView:withTheme:` method is used to make the thumbnail images for the table view. It renders the graph as an image which is why you lose interactivity.</strike> Unless you need the flexibility to quickly add new plots to your app and easily support both MacOS and iOS, I would recommend using one of the other examples as a starting point. The architecture is much simpler and easier to understand.

You need to have a `CPTGraphHostingView` in the visible view hierarchy. Set your graph as its `hostedGraph`. Look at any of the other example apps to see how to set up the hosting view. The graph setup and datasource code in the Plot Gallery plots (e.g., SimpleScatterPlot) is fine and should work anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean it is the renderInLayer:withTheme: method that only creates an image?

The graph made by the SimpleScatterPlot in the PlotGallery-project is available to move and interact with, but can't seem how to set this one up in my own project...

Comment: Ok, now I've finally managed to get a plot in my app. With a little copy-pasting from PlotGallery and reading some (old) tutorials online. Now the main problem is to display the values when I touch one of the plot "buttons". I believe this has something to do with the -(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index-method, but I'm not familiar enough with delagates/datasources to get this to work. Is this method called automatically when i press one of the plot buttons? And what arguments is sent?

Comment: There are examples of that delegate method in the Plot Gallery and other example apps. The arguments are the plot that was touched (so you can use the same delegate for more than one plot) and the index of the point. The index matches the index used to retrieve the point from your datasource.